# Highcharts x axis label text wrapping lost on setting label step

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with the Highcharts label wrapping on the X axis .It is lost on setting the 
label step property as shown in the links below

Correct: http://jsfiddle.net/Bimal/45Lp3/

Incorrect: http://jsfiddle.net/ahwmv/

```
 $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apple Orange: PineApple Mango Grapes (% of Sales)', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        labels: {
            step: 1
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

});

When xAxis.labels.step is set to its default null value ,the text wrapping is done .
Please suggest a way to maintain the wrapping when the labels step is given a numeric value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could replace each space in the name with `<br />` by using the `formatter`:

```
labels: {
    step: 1,
    formatter: function () {
        return this.value.replace(/ /g, '<br />');
    }
}
```

It's not exactly what you want as it doesn't split the name according to the space available between ticks, but maybe you can improve the formatter to better suit your needs (splitting by a given *n* characters for example instead of by space).

See it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/ahwmv/1/).

Comment: Have you seen @SebastianBochan's answer? I think it's better than mine.

Answer (score 12):

You can use width paramter for labales:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahwmv/2/

```
labels: {
            style:{
                width:'50px',
            },
            step: 1
        }
```

Comment: What about Non English Text say, Chinese, without empty space, this is not working.Check:  http://jsfiddle.net/uehbmzgx/

Comment: The above link with non-English text doesn't have any space in between so it's not getting wrapped.