# Setting Highcharts x axis label's width

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I need to set max width for xAxis Label so that when it is too long and rest letters(characters) will go to the next line.

I read [Highcharts x axis label text wrapping lost on setting label step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551135/highcharts-x-axis-label-text-wrapping-lost-on-setting-label-step) and find setting "width" is working fine for English words(separated by empty space).

But when there is no empty space, say "VeryLongLongLongWord" or "这是一个很长很长很长的中文" , that is not working.

I also tried setting `wordWrap: break-word`, still no use.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['This is a long Text', 'VeryLongLongLongWord', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec','这是一个很长很长很长的中文'],
        labels: {
                style:{
                    width:'30px',// not work for text without empty space
                    wordWrap: 'break-word'//no use
                },
                step: 1
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 30
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

fidder: http://jsfiddle.net/uehbmzgx/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Sebastian's solutions works fine.

And I found another solution that using formatter to limit it's width :

```
        labels: {
            useHTML:true,//Set to true
            style:{
                width:'50px',
                whiteSpace:'normal'//set to normal
            },
            step: 1,
            formatter: function () {//use formatter to break word.
                return '<div align="center" style="word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-all;width:50px">' + this.value + '</div>';
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uehbmzgx/5/

Answer (score 3):

You need to add css styles with !important declaration.

CSS

```
.highcharts-axis-labels span{ 
  word-break:break-all!important;
  width:50px!important;
  white-space:normal!important;
}
```

Highcharts

```
 xAxis: {
      categories: ['This is a long Text', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec','这是一个很长很长很长的中文'],
      labels: {
          useHTML:true,
          style:{
                width:'50px',
          },
          step: 1
      }
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uehbmzgx/3/

Answer (score 1):

Best way is dynamically formatting the string :

```
   xAxis : {
          type: 'category', 
          labels: {
            rotation: -90,
            style: {
              color: "#ff0000",
            },
            formatter: function () {//use formatter to check if length of string is greater than 20 and maintain its width.
              if(this.value.length > 20){
                return this.value.substring(0, 17) + '...';
              }
              return this.value;
            }
          },
```